Error launching Android Instant App from Play Store
We've currently created an instant app and are preparing it for release.
When running the instant app in Android Studio, it works normally.
However, when I run the instant app after distributing it to the Play Store, it does not run with an error pop-up.
(Additionally, when the instant app installation fails due to an error, a message attached to the screenshot is displayed in Android Studio Logcat. "Install session failed pkg=MY_PACKAGE")

After checking several cases, it seems that it can only be reproduced in Android 13 or higher.
Please guide me on how to solve this problem. thank you
We expect the instant app to run normally on the Play Store.
